# Selenium error when button is clicked: .MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using safari and selenium on python, I want to make a python selenium program that clicks a `'confirm'` button in an iframe, but it gives me an error or it doesn't work (***the button and the iframe are in the viewport***)

basically anyway I try, if the button is clicked with 'action chains' it gives me the same error (`selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message:`) , or if the button is clicked normally it doesn't have any result (doesn't work)

## Html - iframe

```
<iframe title="Confirm-box" scrolling="no" class="bottom" data-name="bottom">
</iframe>
```

## Html - Button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="submitBtn">
    Confirm
</button>
```

## The iframe

```
iframe2 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[1]
```

## Scroll to the button

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2)
```

## double click the button

```
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Confirm')]")
actionChains.double_click(element).perform()
```

### Expected output:

button is clicked

### Error (action-chains):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message:
```

Comment: Is `element` in the viewport when you try to click it?

Comment: @Trapli Yap, it is, and so is the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can't click directly into an iframe element, first, you need to use a special command in selenium **switchTo**, that allow you to change the context you can switch between (iframes, windows, and alerts).

I don't know the syntax in python but it should be something like this:

```
driver.switchTo().iframe('iframe');
```

You can see the official documentation here:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: I think I already did that with the command: driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2), but it still doesn't work